# Metamask won't display correct balance after creating customrpc for ganache accounts

Tags: erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask, testrpc, ganache

I made a customrpc network on metamask using the correct server and imported a private key from ganache, which worked but the eth balance is displaying 0 when I expected it to display 100.

According to some user reports adding a `/` to the end of the rpc server fixes the problem, but it didn't work for me. I also deleted and reinstalled metamask from chrome, restarted computer and that didn't work either.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and some possible solutions that might fix it? Do i have to install some dependencies or something to sync the two clients? or perhaps I just give it some time to load the proper balances, maybe the network is clogged idk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: /*displaying 0 when I expected it to display 100*/  did you restart ganache after connect ?  if  yes  ganache generated new  address.  I had similar  problems with metamask ganache ,  sometimes  Metamask was crashing stoped showing balance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with copy and pasting the Ganance RPC URL directly from the UX.

Unfortunately, the UX shows `HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545` with a capital HTTP, but you should use `http://127.0.0.1:7545` with a lowercase http, or else it won't work and you will get a balance of 0 in Metamask :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I did the following : when adding my custom RCP link i specified the currency symbol ( eth ). Without this, i would get the balance in dollars ( 100 eth => 410.000 usd or something ).

Comment: After recovering from the mnemonic, It also showed me 0 ETH (but was able to transfer ETH between the account). But like you suggested, I entered ETH as currency symbol in the network settings, then it showed the 100 ETH correclty.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3245#issuecomment-446575218), log out of your metamask, switch your network to localhost 8545 (this option is already available) and then sign in using your ganache's mnemonic.